# c++11 thread sleep/wakeup without lock?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I use a lockfree queue between two threads. One produce data,another consume data. What I want to do is that, when the queue is empty, consumer thread yield cpu until producer thread push data to the queue. I can't call sleep() since there is no way to wakeup a sleeping thread, I think. What I found is std::condition_variable, but it needs a mutex. producer thread need to hold the lock and then notify consumer thread for every data pushing.  Is there a better and lighter way to realize my goal?

Comment: Any mechanism that allows a thread to sleep and wake up is, in effect, a lock. A data structure using such a mechanism is then not lock-free. You can't have both at the same time. Perhaps you may want to reconsider why you thought a lock-free queue was a good idea in the first place.

Comment: you could explore posix semaphores, if available on your platform, i.e. `sem_post`, `sem_wait` etc.   But as always with performance comparisons, measure both approaches (semaphore & condition_variable) to determine which, if any, is faster.

Comment: in addition, in C++20 there may be native support for semaphores (rather than using posix) https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/files/the_developers_2019_concurrency_in_cpp20.pdf#page=27  and http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0514r4.pdf